# How to update a column with ROW_NUMBER() in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have added a new column to the table. Now i want to update this column with values from the function row_number().And i want to do it because i want to remove duplicate entries.  The below mentioned code is not giving the desired output

```
UPDATE tab1
SET rownumber = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) 
             FROM tab1 AS a WHERE a.name = b.name)
FROM tab1 b
```

Problem is that when a new column is added in a table its values are null. Insert into adds new rows in the table but does not replace nulls. How to update null values with row numbers generated by function ROW_NUMBER().

The below mentioned table is what i have

**name          score**

Bank of America 10

Commerce Bank   20

Wells Fargo Bank    135

Bank Midwest    45

Bank of America 10

Commerce Bank   20

now I want the output as after removing the duplicates

**name          score**

Bank of America 10

Commerce Bank   20

Wells Fargo Bank    135

Bank Midwest    45

I was trying to add a new column with unique values to get the desired result.

Comment: Don't you have any primary key column defined in the table ?

Comment: I forgot to mention this table has duplicate records  with two columns name and id and the third column rownumber is added in the table

Comment: NO primary key is not defined in the table

Comment: @sam how do you uniquely identify rows? with `name`?

Comment: Is there a way to update all the null values with unique row numbers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.rownumber = TT.ROW_ID
FROM tab1 AS T
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS ROW_ID
                  ,name
            FROM Tab1) AS TT
    ON T.name = TT.name
```

Comment: @sam you mean that `name` is `NULL`?

Comment: my apologies ... the reason for the bug is because name column has duplicate entries and with inner join total records with become more. For ex if there are 3 records and out of these 3 one is duplicate then inner join will give 4 records and not 3

Comment: @sam that's why you should use a primary key.

Comment: I understand that the table is poorly designed. I have to delete the duplicate entries from the table and for this i need a unique coloumn added in the table. now what should i do.. i can not drop the table

Comment: @sam I don't understand you. Anyway, was this answer usefull?

Comment: I have edited my question with a example table. any help is deeply appriciated

Comment: @sam I think this is beyond the scope of the question. You asked how to update your table, and you have it. Now this is another problem.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your help and time ..i am myself very confused..no issues

Comment: @sam Please, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And for remove duplicate rows at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)